# Magento 2.4.3: Product Customer Group Price not showing in PWA Venia theme

Tags: customer-group, magento2.4.3, pwa-studio, product-prices, venia

I am Working on Venia PWA theme with Magento 2.4.3.

I tried to login from FrontEnd in Venia theme to check Customer Group prices for Product but its not Working.

Where Magento Frontend is showing Customer Group Price for Products.

Anybody has gone through this issue.

**[EDIT]**

After observing graphQL come to know that Customer Group prices are coming but due to PWA caching its not showing , some time it showing price after refreshing browser in 2-3 attempts , but sometimes you will not see price.

Now , new hurdle is how to overcome with this caching issue.

because when you clear site cache , it is also removing data for logged in user.

**[EDIT]**

https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio/issues/3468

Thanks